# django url patterns with 2 parameters

Tags: django

This is simple and obvious but I can't get it right:

I have the following view function declared in urls.py

```
 (r'^v1/(\d+)$', r'custom1.views.v1'),
```

originally I was passing a single parameter to the view function v1.
I want to modify it to pass 2 parameters.  How do I declare the entry in urls.py to take two parameters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe each group in the regex is passed as a parameter (and you can name them if you want):

```
(r'^v1/(\d+)/(\d+)/$', r'custom1.views.v1')
```

Check out the examples at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/. You can also name your groups.

Answer (score 12):

Supposing you want the URL to look like `v1/17/18` and obtain the two parameters `17` and `18`, you can just declare the pattern as:

```
(r'^v1/(\d+)/(\d+)$', r'custom1.views.v1'),
```

Make sure `v1` accepts two arguments in addition to the request object:

```
def v1 ( request, a, b ):
    # for URL 'v1/17/18', a == '17' and b == '18'.
    pass
```

The [first example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example) in the [documentation about the URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/) contains several patterns, the last of which take 2 and 3 parameters.

Answer (score 12):

Somewhere along the line I got in the habit of naming them directly in the regex, although honestly I don't know if it makes a difference.

```
#urls:
(r'^v1/(?P<variable_a>(\d+))/(?P<variable_b>(\d+))/$', r'custom1.views.v1')

#views:
def v1(request, variable_a, variable_b):
    pass
```

Also, it's very Django to end the url with a trailing slash - [Django Design Philosophy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/misc/design-philosophies/#definitive-urls), FYI

Answer (score 6):

in django 2.x and 3.x:

url:

```py
    path("courses/<slug:param1>/<slug:param2>", views.view_funct, name="double_slug")
```

template:

```html
    <a href="{% url 'double_slug' param1 param2 %}">Click {{param2}}!</a>
```

Comment: Do the 2 parameters have to be separated by a slash? Could you have something like: `http://example.com/courses?start=01-01-2012&end=01-31-2012` . Although i don't know what the URLconf would look like.

Comment: @moonraker yes you can do so, but I guess it's a convention to use slashes