# how to send two parameters in url on django template language?

Tags: django

```
{% url 'start' commission.id applie.id %}
```

Like the above code, I am trying to send two model id but I don't know the right structure for it. and above code wouldn't work.

```
path('start/<int:post_id>', views.start, name="start"),

def start(request,post_id):
```

and also if i get two parenthesis, how should i modify the above url and view code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django url patterns with 2 parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587712/django-url-patterns-with-2-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Try to go with this way..

In urls.py--

```
path('profile/<name> <email>', views.profile, name='profile'),
#As path have space, it will take %20 there, 
#you can change it accordingly. best to use '-' instead of space
#http://example.com/profile/myname%20myemail@example.com
```

In the link--

```
href="{% url 'profile' name='myname' email='myemail@example.com' %}"
```

In the views.py--

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def profile(request, name, email):
   return render(request, "profile.html", {'name': name, 'email':email})
```